# how to fold xml file (or specifically build.xml)

Tags: code-folding, xml, nxml

I am using spacemacs nXML mode to edit build.xml (java ant configuration file), the file is very long, how to fold and unfold it?

Comment: Here is a related link to some code folding for nXML-mode that I wrote up some time ago -- perhaps you could modify it to suit your needs.  The title of the thread is **How can I fold arbitrary tags with nxml-mode?**:  http://superuser.com/a/787030/206164

Comment: Not really what you're looking for but `set-selective-display` function can help you hide/un-hide some part of your file based on the indention. Also, `occur` is probably the best way to go when editing a large file, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this hook:

```
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook 'hs-minor-mode)
```

After that put this in your init.el file or somewhere it'll be loaded.

```
(define-key nxml-mode-map (kbd "C-c h") 'hs-toggle-hiding)
```

If you now press `C-c h` it will fold the xml at the element where your cursor is.

Comment: I guess you need to have hs-minor-mode enabled too? Should perhaps be part of the answer.

Comment: This actually does nothing in my Emacs 24.3.1. Do I need a specific Emacs version? Or hide-show mode version?

Comment: I'm using emacs 24.5.1 with nothing special. You of course need to be in an xml. I'll have a look at what may be missing..